# Unknown reason for syntax error in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, sql-grant

Error message states "SQL syntax error NEAR 'table, alter table,..."  NO ERROR NUMBER GIVEN

```
CREATE USER admin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';  

GRANT select, update, insert, delete, create table, alter table, drop table, 
    create index, drop index, create routine, create procedure, create function  
ON test.*   
TO admin@localhost;*
```

All of the items I am trying to grant are valid permissions but when it gets to the first "table" in the list it just does not like it, am I missing something or is there a conflict that I just don't understand.

TIA

Comment: You should really read [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) and stick to ***existing*** privileges

Comment: @fvu I was looking for that link. you did. now, she can do it herself.

Comment: yes I am reading the manual, just find parts of it confusing. I ran a SHOW GRANTS FOR ... and found out what was existing, I just listed those for display purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table` is not needed:

```
GRANT select, update, insert, delete, create, alter, drop
ON test.*  TO admin@localhost;
```

I'm not sure about that how to add procedure, function privileges, I'll find it.

as fvu mentioned, you can find grant privileges MySQL Manual. especially for PROCEDURE, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html#grant-routine-privileges

### UPDATED

I have read your comment on your question. `output is from SHOW GRANTS ...`. I have googled about it. output of SHOW GRANTS looks like that can run directly in MySQL. but it can't. (this fact I just  didn't know. thanks)

and how to find something like you want...  can you try this?:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES
WHERE GRANTEE = 'user_id@hosname';
```

You can see which real privileges name user@hostname has... good. but hard to make `GRANT ...` Percona has interesting feature  like this:

```
 SELECT sql_grants
 FROM common_schema.sql_show_grants;
```

I found it [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23265/mysql-show-grants-for-all-users).

Thanks alot! I have learned many skills for your question!!!

Comment: yes thank you, I will try it, I also just figured that out about not adding the word 'table'